# web.py and JavaScript problems

Tags: javascript, web.py

I have been trying to make a page which combines web.py and JavaScript, and with the following code:

```
$code: 
     def getContents(fname): 
          a = req.get(fname) 
          return a.content 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
     document.write("$getContents('http://mysite.net')"); 
</script>
```

Here, `req` is passed on my template's `$def with()` function, being a module object of the [Python Requests module](http://python-requests.org), from which I execute methods.)

Problem is, the document is blank, which means the `document.write` function got no input. Is there a way around this? Am I doing this in a wrong way?

**EDIT**: The function output is not empty; if you use plain HTML to print it it will just work.

Thanks in advance.

(I've also posted this question on the **web.py Google group**, got no answer yet.)

Comment: Can you show the "View Source" contents of the rendered page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable json encoder in template globals, and use it in your javascript code.

```
import json
template_globals = {"json_encode": json.dumps}
render = web.template.render(config.template_dir, globals=template_globals, base="layout")
```

Then in your template

```
<script>
var obj = $:json_encode({"html": getContents('http://mysite.net')});
document.write(obj.html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have quotes in rendered content, and it invalidates javascript.

Comment: Why won't you show the source of generated page? It will be easy to see the problem.

Comment: The source is at http://pastie.org/2914370; it renders http://matoe.co.cc/patcher.txt for an test.

Comment: The problem is that your javascript string is broken by the line breaks.

Comment: So is there a way to escape `\n` instead of `NEWLINE`? (You're right :))

Comment: Check my second answer, just use json.dumps to properly encode string for javascript. You then won't have to worry about quotes or newlines, etc.